# Trying to add jquery to Tapestry 5

Tags: jquery, tapestry

I'm using tapestry 5.2.6 right in my project. But now I'm trying to add jquery code to it.

To do it, I added the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.got5</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry5-jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once I do it, my application that works fine, starts to fail and don't run, showing errors in Classes that didn't fail before

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'convocatoriaDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void es.udc.pojo.modelutil.dao.GenericDaoHibernate.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [pojo-horarios-spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;

Are there any other method to work with jquery and tapestry (I've never worked with jquery...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but in the changelogs on the projects github I see:

> 3.0.0 : Switch to Tapestry 5.3 (new JavaScript Layer) add Components : Gallery

So maybe you need to update to Tapestry 5.3 or use an older version of tapestry5-jquery (2.6.6)